# I need to draw a line moving with the cursor, but I want to avoid redrawing the whole window every 100ms

Tags: graphics, gtk, flicker, cairo, xlib

I have a program which displays a ruler on the screen, and with Xlib it polls for the cursor position every 100ms and updates the display.  The display consists of numbers/lines etc, in particular a line indicating the position of the cursor (which is why it updates).

The problem is that the old line needs to be erased and the content underneath restored, so I have to redraw the whole window to reflect a change in position.  Doing this 10 times a second results in a very flickery program.

I *could* only redraw the ruler after I have confirmed that the cursor is in a position to change the indicator line (i.e. within the bounds of the ruler), but it would still flicker pretty bad when it *was* updating.

Sort of a noob to GTK and Xlib and all, any advice would be appreciated.

Code is at https://github.com/zjmichen/zRuler

Comment: You should check gtk-demos app, there some scribble examples, that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Well you have arrived at one of the earliest problems faced when cursors were being implemented!! Cursor changes are so frequent that redrawing full window every time just doesn't make any sense! Coming to your problem, look at what is needed & what exactly you are doing. Do you need to update the full window when cursor moves? No. You need to update only a section of the window so don't update the whole window. Off the top, I can think  of 2 ways of reducing flicker:
1. Simple way is to make use of [`GdkCursor`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Cursors.html). Create a new cursor from the pixmap (Sample provided on the developer page) with the shape of your need, a line in your case. [Associate](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor) cursor with the `GdkWindow` of your application's main window. This way you don't have to track cursor & draw the line. The cursor itself will appear as the line (so you don't to bother about clearing & redrawing it). Now in the timer callback where you redraw the complete window, redraw only the component which has to be updated on cursor position change. This should hopefully reduce the flicker as you are not drawing all the components.
2. In case you don't want to use `GdkCursor`, you could create a separate transparent window *on top of* application window dedicated to cursor. In this approach you can update only the cursor window & the component in the application window which is to updated on change in cursor position. This way other components in the application window are not redrawn each time & this hopefully should also be able to reduce flicker.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I'm not sure if I understand GdkCursor correctly - I had thought it merely replaces the standard arrow with another pixmap, which wouldn't help me when my cursor was out of the window.  From what you say, it sounds like it would appear in the window even if my cursor was above the window.  Is this right?
The problem is I need the position line to update even if the cursor is above the ruler, but still between the ruler's ends.
I had also thought of something like method 2, but honestly I'd rather not go to that trouble if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Yes you are right. It replaces the cursor within the window. I was not aware that you need to update line even when the cursor is outside the application window. Hmm in that case 2nd method should to work. Let see if I can think of something better or if someone else can provide a better alternative. Good Luck!